# C Macros - operator pasting?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to use macros to paste an operator? (similar to token pasting but with the actual operator.

Example:

```
#define DO(a, operator, b) a ##operator b

DO(1, +, 3); // 4
DO(4, <<, 1); // 8
```

Note - this is a very simplified example. My actual use case is that I'm working on an algorithm with lots of bit shift operations happening and I'd like to be able to pass which shift operator I need to the macro (`>>` or `<<`) to keep things a bit simpler.

Comment: Compiler error: `error: pasting "4" and "<<" does not give a valid preprocessing token DO(4, <<, 1);`

Comment: I'm hoping someone can at least point me in the direction of some kind of syntax that can achieve this result :)

Comment: Have you tried `#define DO(a, operator, b) a operator b`?

Comment: Yeah - that gives `error: ‘operator’ undeclared (first use in this function)`

Comment: You *do* know what [concatenation `##` operator](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation) does? For `DO(1, +, 3)` it creates e.g. `1+` *as a **single** token*, and the preprocessor then wants to preprocess that token but it's not a legal token.

Comment: @JoelCox: [I can't reproduce that](http://ideone.com/lEs5Nf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply

```
#define DO(a, operator, b) ((a) operator (b))
```

? (also added some safety parentheses.)

Comment: Note that this is C and not C++, so `operator` isn't a reserved keyword (I made that same mistake). But I agree it should be avoided, just in case the C code ever interfaces with C++.

Comment: @Cornstalks In fact you're right; after posting my answer, I tested the code (just in case) with some already available C++ code at hand, and the syntax highlighting reminded me that `operator` was reserved; but by the time, I forgot that the question was tagged C… stupid oversight on my part.